# External USB hdd slows to kb/s speeds and errors out

Tags: 20.04, usb, hard-drive, xhci-hcd

I had a 3.5" spinning disc Toshiba 1TB hdd in my pc but want to use it externally for backup purposes. I am running Ubuntu focal 20.04 LTS. I have tried two different brands of USB caddy and power supplies. Both error out in the same manner, they work long enough to copy some files for 5 minutes, then it gets progressively slower until it becomes unusable. I have tried both a Seagate and a Toshiba hdd in the caddy.

Here are the errors i see with dmesg. I do not know how to interpret them.
I suspect i have a mobo issue, but don't have a second computer right now to test out that theory. what should i do. I have tried both the blue and black USB ports, neither work for me.

```
[ 6736.009527] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 6912.818607] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 6912.968178] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 6912.968179] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 6912.968180] usb 3-2: Product: USB3.0 Device
[ 6912.968181] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 6912.968182] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: WD-WXE1E14MVJ21
[ 6912.970370] scsi host5: uas
[ 6912.970961] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  DT01ACA100       0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 6912.971766] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 6912.972741] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 6912.972742] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 6912.972984] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 6912.972985] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 6912.973332] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 6912.973597] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[ 6913.176654]  sdc: sdc1
[ 6927.054231] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 7027.859487] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#23 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[ 7027.859496] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 69 d8 00 00 08 00
[ 7027.859506] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 7027.859509] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7027.859625] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[ 7027.859632] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 69 e8 00 00 10 00
[ 7027.875438] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7028.007666] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7028.157269] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7058.587648] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7058.587779] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[ 7058.587785] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7058.587791] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#14 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[ 7058.587795] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 69 d8 00 00 08 00
[ 7058.715957] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7058.865468] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7089.311844] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7089.311926] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#16 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[ 7089.311930] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7089.444038] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7089.593494] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7120.032058] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7120.032243] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 7120.032258] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7120.160347] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7120.310351] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7150.748276] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7150.748357] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 7150.748360] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7150.876584] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7151.026200] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7181.468508] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7181.468743] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 7181.468747] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7181.596716] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7181.746736] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7181.747158] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_RESET driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 7181.747165] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 7181.747169] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 7181.747174] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 68 00 00 01 d0 00
[ 7181.747177] print_req_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[ 7181.747183] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1953523712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 58 prio class 0
[ 7220.372796] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 7220.372805] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 64 00 00 02 00 00
[ 7220.388822] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7220.516976] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7220.667141] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7251.097001] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7251.097292] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 7251.097298] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 64 00 00 02 00 00
[ 7251.225237] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7251.375273] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7281.825213] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7281.825307] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#29 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 7281.825313] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 64 00 00 02 00 00
[ 7281.953409] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7282.103380] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 7326.869551] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[ 7326.869558] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 67 88 00 00 68 00
[ 7326.869567] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 7326.869570] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 67 00 00 00 80 00
[ 7326.885602] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 7327.013746] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 7327.167361] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

Comment: Ubuntu *focal* 20?  So you're asking about a Ubuntu Core 20 install? and not Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (both 20.04 & the smaller/reduced 20 are both *focal*)